# How come print_r does not output anything on my live server but works fine on my localhost?

Tags: php, arrays, session, printing

I'm building a web-application and currently testing out how to retrieve values from the server database and display it on my page.  My connection to my database is working just fine.

In my localhost, I run the code `print_r($_SESSION['user'];` where `$_SESSION['user']` stores the user's login session and it works fine.  Here's what it outputs on my localhost:

`Array([0]=>1 [1]=>Bob [2]=>Dylan [3]=>Bob.Dylan@gmail.com)`

where Bob is the user's `firstname`, Dylan is his `lastname`, and Bob.Dylan@gmail.com is his `email`.

So that's all good.

But when it comes to my live server and I run the same `print_r($_SESSION['user'];` code again it displays absolutely nothing.

I'm eventually working my way to my objective of displaying all the related user's info on the database (basically, their profile page) so I thought I'd start with this and go from there but I can't even get the `print_r` function to work correctly.

Can anyone help me?

EDIT:

- My connection to both my localhost and live server database is working fine

My code:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user]))
{
     print_r($_SESSION['user']);
}
else
{
     echo "Session is not set" 
}
```

Comment: Either the session isn't started, or it's simply empty/not set.

Comment: Can you add the code when you are trying in your live server?

Comment: I've set the session_start(); at the beginning of the page before any output.

Comment: @DorukAyar I've just typed in my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably falling under the else part. Your session may not have been set correctly.

Try this:

```
var_dump($_SESSION);  // Check your session variable

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    print_r($_SESSION['user']);
} else {
    echo "Session is not set"; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the following;

`print_r(array_values($_SESSION['user']));`

or

`var_dump($_SESSION['user]);`

Answer (score 0):

So you have syntax errors. It should be:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
//                     ^^^
{
     print_r($_SESSION['user']);
}
else
{
     echo "Session is not set";
     //                      ^^^
}
```

You did:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user]))
{
     print_r($_SESSION['user']);
}
else
{
     echo "Session is not set" 
}
```

> Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

According to php manual you probably need to turn on output buffering using ob_start() function.

Please follow the note section from this url: [print_r manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)